# Is this statement wrong?

Tags: math-mode

```
\begin{equation}
   \label{eq3}
   T = (1-\alpha )I+\alpha S, 
   \end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 \langle x-\mbox{ }\mbox{ }z,P_c x-P_c z\rangle  \mbox{ }\ge\mbox{ } 0 \forall x\in C  
\end{equation}
```

is this statement wrong?

Comment: Why all the `\mbox{ }`?  From a code point of view the statement is not wrong, as it compiles without errors.

Comment: Can you expand on your question? What are you trying to do? Is this code not working for you?

Answer (score 3):

The code is not syntactically wrong, but the typesetting is.

1. The spaces you add after the minus sign are improper.
2. The spaces around the greater-than-or-equal-to sign are excessive.
3. You miss a space before the for-all sign.

You should trust in the automatic spacing inserted by TeX, except that, in this case, the subscript c clashes with the following letter. This can be cured with `\,`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\langle x-\mbox{ }\mbox{ }z,P_c x-P_c z\rangle  \mbox{ }\ge\mbox{ } 0 \forall x\in C
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\langle x-z,P_c\,x-P_c\,z\rangle\ge 0,\quad \forall x\in C
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You should have no doubt that the second formula is typeset correctly.

Comment: I use latex resently .All right, is this equation written like this\begin{equation}
\langle x-P_c\,x,P_c\,z-z\rangle\ge 0,\quad \forall z\in C  
\end{equation}

Comment: @R.İ Yes, but you should read an introductory manual, such as http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html